# How to get a single column with Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-5

I have code to retrieve all columns from a entity class against a search criteria. But I want a specific column value instead of complete column values.

My code is -

```
Main main;
main = repo.Find<Main>(m => m.Code == criteria.code);
```

where `Main` is entity class, `repo` is repository and `criteria` is search criteria class.  Now I want to get a specific column name, say `id`. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 6):

Assuming that `Find` is returning an `IQueryable<T>`, then you can use a projection:

```
repo.Find<Main>(m => m.Code == criteria.code).Select(m => m.Column);
```

Comment: No its not returning an `IQueryable<T>`, its returning `Single`

Comment: You'll need to modify the repository then, otherwise the projection won't be done at the database level, which may or may not be a concern.

Answer (score 3):

```
var column =
    from m in repo
    where m.Code == criteria.code
    select m.SomeColumn;
```

Answer (score 3):

You do a query projection with the `Select` method:

```
repo.Mains.Where(m => m.Code == criteria.code).Select(m => m.Id);
```

On a related note, you should read [Getting Started with Entity Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/ee712907.aspx). It'll give you a good idea of the query operators.